# kotlin in intellij unresolved reference testng or junit when adding unit tests

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I am trying to add unit testing to my project. What I did:

- Created a function that returns what it is given.
- Right clicked → Generate … → Test …
- Selected TestNG (I tried after with Junit5, and got same result).
- Selected functions to test
- TestNG Library not found in the module: click fix, selected first one (org.testng.testng:6.14.3), clicked OK
- Clicked OK

Test code was generated, but there is error message: `Unresolved reference: testng`. There is a similar message for JUnit5. In source code the (first) error is in `import org.testng.Assert` on the word `testng`.

The project window now shows External Libraries → testng → testng-6.14.3.jar → org.testng → Assert (there are other branches).

## A hack that worked

- File → Project structure → Libraries
- `+` → Java
- `/usr/share/java/testng.jar`
- Do you really want to replace old library 'testng'? : click yes

What is happening?: Why is library not found?

---

- IntelliJ Idea community addition 2020.2 from snap on Debian Gnu/Linux.
- I am new to kotlin, did some Java in the 1990, and experienced in other languages.

Comment: (The first steps are irrelevant where you press fix to download btw). Are you using a build tool like `gradle` or `maven`?

Comment: @Kdev I am not consciously using a build tool. I am just clicking run (this makes it build and run, when I don't get this error). I have maven, gradle, and ant installed: they were installed and enabled by default (as part of the intellij install).

Comment: I strongly suggest you add build.gradle or pom.xml file and manage test dependencies via build tool.

Comment: @kdev It seems that you are suggesting explicitly managing dependencies. I was assuming that it was being done for me, however I can't find which file it is, so am unsure what I need to put into revision control (but that is a different problem). However that is all that I understood. I have no ideas how to do it, or what I should add to the dependencies, or why the IDE said it was adding it, but did not.

Comment: Dependencies are being managed automatically, you only have to specify which library you want to use. If you are planning on putting your project inside revision control, then having build tool is an absolutely must, as other people downloading your project will have identical setup with correct version, etc. irrespective of which IDE they use and everything will work out of the box.

Comment: Check out [gradle guide](https://guides.gradle.org/creating-new-gradle-builds/)  for how to set up it for the project. Or simply create new project from Intellij. File>New>Project>Gradle (check **Kotlin DSL build script**) and select Kotlin/JVM as additional library>next>finish. And then copy files from your existing project into this new one.